# refused to display page due to xframe option sameorgin

Tags: javascript, java, applet

I am trying to show applet in iframe , I am getting this error in chrome

> Refused to display 'http://java.com/en/download/chrome.jsp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

in IE  10

> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
>   http://java.com/dt-redirect?returnPage=

my js code to launch applet

> deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');

can we catch this error?  I want to catch this kind or error and display some msg.  I tried adding try catch to **deployJava.runApplet**  but  control never goes to catch block.

Comment: *"I am getting this error in chrome"*  Chrome is set to remove support for applets entirely.  Time to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this any longer - you're trying to do something which amounts to cross-site scripting, sounds like.  Perhaps show some code, if you think you're not trying to pull something from somewhere other than the original origin?

Comment: I am trying to load applet and if browser detects that java is not enabled or not the latest version, or not the version applet needs, then  browser redirects to java plugin download page and becauise java download url is a different domain I get this error.

Comment: I'm going to go with what @Andrew Thompson said in his comment - applets are on the way out.  That said, however, the issue is that the applet is trying to launch a URL in an iFrame, which points to a different domain.  This isn't allowed by anybody, any longer, because it presents a security issue.  You're going to have to either live with it, or live without the applet.